# formatting a list for a hash in perl with sed - adding single quotes

Tags: bash, sed

How can I get single quotes around each bareword

```
$ cat /tmp/foojoo
my $header = "Symbol
Exchange
Expiry
oCQJoinEdgeMult
oCQEdgeMult
oCQKeepEdgeMult
oTOEdgeMult
oTOMinEdgeMult
```

But can't seem to just get single quotes aroung the barewords ; 
like this  this is what i want.

```
my $header = " 'Symbol' 
'Exchange'
'Expiry' 
'oCQJoinEdgeMult'
'oCQEdgeMult'
'oCQKeepEdgeMult'
'oTOEdgeMult' 
'oTOMinEdgeMult'
```

I tried :

```
cat /tmp/foojoo | sed -e 's/^$/'\w'/g'
cat /tmp/foojoo | sed -e 's/^$/' '/g'
cat /tmp/foojoo | sed -e 's/\w/'\w'/g'
cat /tmp/foojoo | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("\"%s\" ",$i);printf("\n");}' | tr '"' '\''
```

Comment: What's the actual input?

Comment: it is just a list. there are actually thousand in the list, and I want to get single quotes around each word in the list. Aftre i get the single quotes, i can add a ' => 1 ' and turn this list in to a perl hash

Comment: Why the last line `oAskMaxQSizeMult";` and few other lines isn't shown on the expected output?

Comment: Well the actual list has thousands of entires - this is just a truncated list. I suppose I could truncat the file that I trucated.  - hang on a sec, let me get to work on lining up these two lists - make them into one

Comment: there we go @Avinash Raj - the oTOMinEdgeMult ends on each list - all nice and tidy. a tidy list.

Comment: please edit your question. Did you want to remove any lines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59836/discussion-between-capser-and-avinash-raj).

Comment: this is quite a quandry

Comment: get into the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59836/discussion-between-capser-and-avinash-raj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed "s/\w\+$/'&'/" file
```

Comment: the backslash w is the regex for word - why did you escape the plus sign and why the dollar sign. Also what does the ampersand do?

Comment: @casper the `\w` is shorthand for a word character class, `\+` is a regexp metacharacter meaning one or more of the previous character and `$` anchors the expression to the end of the line. `&` in the RHS of a substitution command refers to the match on the LHS i.e. the last word in the line.

Answer (score 1):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -pe "s/(\w+)$/'\1'/g" file
my $header = "'Symbol'
'Exchange'
'Expiry'
'oCQJoinEdgeMult'
'oCQEdgeMult'
'oCQKeepEdgeMult'
'oTOEdgeMult'
'oTOMinEdgeMult'
```

---

```
$ perl -pe "s/(\w+)$/'\1'/g" file | sed "s/\"'/\" '/g"
my $header = " 'Symbol'
'Exchange'
'Expiry'
'oCQJoinEdgeMult'
'oCQEdgeMult'
'oCQKeepEdgeMult'
'oTOEdgeMult'
'oTOMinEdgeMult'
```

Comment: nice!!!!! the parenthesis captures the word, but why use the dollar sign, also - waht is "\1"?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your string is just a list of words.  How about do this:

```
my @words = qw(Symbol Exchange Expiry oCQJoinEdgeMult oCQEdgeMult oCQKeepEdgeMult oTOEdgeMult oTOMinEdgeMult);
for my $word (@words)
{
  $word = "'$word'";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v s="'" '
{
    if(NR==1) {
        sub("\"","\""s,$NF)
        $NF=$NF s
    } else {
        $0=s $0 s
    }
}1' file
```

Output:

```
my $header = "'Symbol'
'Exchange'
'Expiry'
'oCQJoinEdgeMult'
'oCQEdgeMult'
'oCQKeepEdgeMult'
'oTOEdgeMult'
'oTOMinEdgeMult'
```